# Query to find days since last value of a column is continuously observed - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table, the task is to write a SQL query (in PostgreSQL/MySQL - PostgreSQL preferred) that returns the days since last value of a column was continuously observed:

**Table**: TestResult

[image]

So, for the student with 'StudentID=1001' and 'TestID=2001', since Grade 'A' was last observed on 2018-12-04 00:00:00 then the query must return the 'Date' difference for record with ID=5014 and ID=5012; which is DATE_PART('day', 2018-12-04 00:00:00 - 2018-11-23 00:00:00)

Can anyone please guide me on how to write the query? This table will contain millions of records hence performance is of high concern. A better table schema structure can also be suggested if required.

Comment: In the example, shouldn't the record for Grade B be also shown? and how is the date difference to be shown for the last record 5017. Please post the expected output results as well

Comment: Since the continuity of grade 'A' was broken by 'B' (record id=5015) the output should be date difference between ID 5012-5014 and not between 5012-5017.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rows that you care about only using window functions:

```
select tr.*
from (select tr.*,
             max(tr.dated) filter (where tr.grade <> tr.last_grade) over (partition by tr.studentID, tr.testID) as max_other_grade_date
      from (select tr.*,
                   first_value(tr.grade) over (partition by tr.studentID, tr.testID order by tr.dated desc) as last_grade
            from testresult tr
          ) tr
     ) tr
where max_other_grade_date is null or dated > max_other_grade_date ;
```

A simple aggregation then gets the days that you want:

```
select tr.studentID, tr.testID,
       max(dated) - min(dated)
from (select tr.*,
             max(tr.dated) filter (where tr.grade <> tr.last_grade) over (partition by tr.studentID, tr.testID) as max_other_grade_date
      from (select tr.*,
                   first_value(tr.grade) over (partition by tr.studentID, tr.testID order by tr.dated desc) as last_grade
            from testresult tr
          ) tr
     ) tr
where max_other_grade_date is null or dated > max_other_grade_date    
group by tr.studentID, tr.testID;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/38beb/10) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT t.StudentID, t.TestID, t.Grade, 
       min(t.Dated) as start_date, max(t.Dated) as last_date,
       max(t.Dated) - min(t.Dated) as how_many_days
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM TestResult
  WHERE StudentID = 1001 AND TestID=2001
  ORDER BY dated DESC LIMIT 1
) last_record
JOIN TestResult t
ON t.StudentID = last_record.StudentID
   AND t.TestID = last_record.TestID
   and t.Dated > (
     SELECT max( Dated ) FROM TestResult tt
     WHERE tt.StudentID = last_record.StudentID
       AND tt.TestID = last_record.TestID
       AND tt.Grade <> last_record.Grade
   )
GROUP BY t.StudentID, t.TestID, t.Grade
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/38beb/7

```
| studentid | testid | grade | start_date |  last_date | how_many_days |
|-----------|--------|-------|------------|------------|---------------|
|      1001 |   2001 |     A | 2018-11-23 | 2018-12-04 |            11 |
```

In order to make this query faster, create a multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX some_name ON TestResult ( StudentID, TestID )
```

Comment: Thanks @krokodilko ! However, this query might fail when there is a single entry for a particular StudentID & TestID.